# AWS SES .csv attachment becomes garbled on iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-ses

I'm using AWS's simple email service to dispatch emails with a .csv attachment. The file gets through without issue on desktop and the Android mail app, but iOS's default mail app gives a corrupted preview of the file.

My code:

```
message = "This is a message that appears above the attached file.";
csv = "1,2,3,4,5,6";

head = "Subject: Subject\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n";
head += "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\n\n";
head += "--NextPart\nContent-Type: text/plain\n\n";

tail = "\n\n--NextPart\nContent-Type: application/csv; name=\"a.csv\"\n";
tail += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\nContent-Disposition: attachment\n\n";
tail += csv.toString("base64") + "\n\n--NextPart--";

ses_mail = head + message + tail;

await sendCSV(mailList, ses_mail);
```

I've tried using different content types, and specifying the encoding with a BOM in front of the attachment, but neither seemed to work.

I'm also entertaining the possibility that the file *can't* be opened correctly on iOS, as it may simply choose to ignore BOM headings and assume UTF-16 or some other encoding which isn't getting used.

Any advice would be appreciated.